# Extend the Web Animations API

Tags: javascript

**What I want**:
Make the `animate` method of the Web Animations API chainable. (For instance, the jQuery `animate` method is chainable. You can do something like `elem.animate(...).animate(...)`).

**What I have so far**: I've read [this](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) article. It basically says I need to clone the original `animate` method, apply the original arguments to my `newAnimate` method, and then replace the original `animate` method with my `newAnimate` method.

So I wrote the following:

```js
const originalAnimate = Element.prototype.animate; 

const newAnimate = function(keyframes, options) {
 console.log('used the new animate method instead');
 originalAnimate.apply(this, arguments); // apply original arguments
 return this; // make the animate method chainable
}

Element.prototype.animate = newAnimate; // overwrite original animate

document.querySelector('h1').animate(
  [
    { color: 'black' },
    { color: 'green' }
  ],
  {
    duration: 500,
  }
);
```

```html
<h1>Change its color</h1>
```

I expected this to change the color of the headline (I did not chain anything yet). If I run the JavaScript in the browser, it logs 5000 times `'used the new animate method instead'` to the console, before a max call size error occurs.
What did I miss here?

Comment: Your code works for me in both Firefox and Chrome. Just one message is logged.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I updated my code. The max call size error is probably related to the browser console. Please have a look at my newest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here at StackOverflow it seems to work now. I had a little typo in my initial post (which I fixed there). Moreover, what confused me was the fact that the styles are reverted after the animation finished. So after the color changed to green, it became black immediately.

The following snippet chains another `animate` method. Unfortunately, only the second animation is applied.

```js
const originalAnimate = Element.prototype.animate; 

const newAnimate = function(keyframes, options) {
 originalAnimate.apply(this, arguments); // apply original arguments
 return this; // make the animate method chainable
}

Element.prototype.animate = newAnimate; // overwrite original animate

const OPTIONS =  {
    duration: 1000,
  }

document.querySelector('div').animate(
  [
    { width: '100px' },
    { width: '500px' }
  ],
  OPTIONS
)
.animate(
  [
    { width: '500px' },
    { width: '100px' }
  ],
  OPTIONS
);
```

```css
div.animate {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate">
  
</div>
```

**How can I wait for the animation to finish?**

Comment: The "real" `.animate()` method returns an `Animation` object, which provides a property called "finished" whose value is a Promise. You can add a `.then` callback to that Promise or use `await`.

Comment: Oh and you can use `fill: "forwards"` in  your `.animate()` options object to leave the animated properties as-is when the animation finishes.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?

Comment: First you have to retain the `.animate()` return value, and then you can just do something like `theAnimation.finished.then(function() { /* do things; */ });` — when the animation is finished the callback will be invoked.

Comment: I think that in order to get the chaining behavior you want, it might work better to have your own API that manages the `Animation` objects in some way.